# Texture Packer won't run

Tags: libgdx, texturepacker

I downloaded texture packer here https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/downloads/detail?name=gdx-texturepacker-3.2.0.zip&can=2&q=

When I run the .jar file it just shuts down before even displaying the gui. Is anyone experiencing a similar problem? I am running OSX El Capitan.

Comment: Did you find how to run it? It's not a problem with Java but an error gets displayed: `Usage: inputDir [outputDir] [packFileName] [settingsFileName]`

Comment: I found out a workaround by providing arguments via configuration editor. But there's no GUI displayed.

Comment: To be honest I just switched to Windows based computer and did all texture making there. That worked.

Comment: Well, okay. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've got the same problem, on a macbook running Siera

Answer (score 2):

The project is quite old so you can try it's successor: gdx-texture-packer-gui.

> [The] project is a successor of Aurelien Ribon's project with whole new
>   GUI and features.

You can download the tool here:
https://github.com/crashinvaders/gdx-texture-packer-gui/releases

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Java runtime environment installed on your computer or just the Java development kit? I don't use the texture packer, but I had a similar problem with the Android SDK manager (it shut down before displaying the GUI) on a new computer where I had only installed the Java JDK. After installing the JRE then it worked fine.

Comment: Users-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)  // This is from terminal. I think I got JRE installed

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Create a txt file and change its extension to ".bat". Right click to file and select modify. Copy this into file: 
"java -jar "C:\Users\fat2019\Desktop\gdx-texturepacker-3.2.0\gdx-texturepacker.jar" Change path to your own where gdx-texturepacker.jar file is. Then save and close. Double click file.

edit: this is for windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Using Windows 7 I have to do this:

---

1. Go to your java directory and copy your java path

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin`

2. Right click on *my computer*,
3. Click *properties*
4. Go to "Advanced system settings" click ,
5. Click on *Environment variables*.
6. Go to *System variables* section, and you will find an entry called *path*.
7. Double click on *path*
8. Add a semicolon (;) to the end of that line
9. After the semicolon paste your path previously copied: *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin*
10. Apply

---

It must be enough. Your file should run at this point.
Double click it and go to the end, put a semicolon and paste your path, apply and ok. It should run now.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac I downloaded the free version of https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/download

This saves as .txt rather than .atlas for some reason.

After adding the animation I got errors in batch.draw ... casting to TextureRegion fixed that.

As always, I have no idea if this will cause problems later but there you go. Looks good so far. :)﻿